# Why is Azure API Management hides response body for status codes 4** and 5**

Tags: httpresponse, http-status-codes, azure-api-management

I created an API in Azure API Management and I realized that APIM actually hides some of the bodies I return in responses. I get 200, but I don't get 404, 401, or 500.

I understand that it's better to control what is returned and that we don't want to give the end-user HTML with 500 error body.

But, I use 404 or 401 in my API and I returned some information in the response body. Is there a possibility to control what is being returned for certain status codes?

Comment: APIM itself does not touch response body returned by backend unless there are policies instructing it to do so. You could check effective policy for a given operation and product to see if there is something that removes the body.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`set-body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies?redirectedfrom=MSDN#SetBody) policy to set the message body for incoming and outgoing requests. To access the message body you can use the `context.Request.Body` property or the [`context.Response.Body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policies/filter-response-content#policy), depending on whether the policy is in the inbound or outbound section.

You can custom response body with below code:

```
<when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)">
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="404" reason="NotFound">
            <set-header name="Content-Type">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>@{
                var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
                foreach (var key in new [] {"HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."}) {
                response.Property (key).Remove ();
            }
            return response.ToString();
      }</set-body>
     </return-response>
</when>
```

Comment: doesn't work.  Throws errors in APIM when try to save